# Problem installing openweathermap Gnome extension

Tags: gnome, gnome-shell-extension, 23.10

I am trying to install the openweathermap extension for Gnome 45 ([link](https://github.com/toppk/gnome-shell-extension-openweather)) (Ubuntu 23.10). When I am running the command `make && make install`, I am getting the following error:

```
fatal: No names found, cannot describe anything.
msgfmt -c po/ar.po -o po/ar.mo
make: msgfmt: No such file or directory
make: *** [Makefile:61: po/ar.mo] Error 127
```

Can someone please help me in figuring out what am I doing wrong?

Comment: You're likely doing nothing wrong - except you don't have the `gettext` (GNU Internationalization utilities) package installed on your system. Did you check the table of dependencies in [Install From Source](https://github.com/toppk/gnome-shell-extension-openweather#install-from-source) section of the README.md file?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks to [comment](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1497987/problem-installing-openweathermap-gnome-extension?noredirect=1#comment2624129_1497987) from user [steeldriver](https://askubuntu.com/users/178692/steeldriver), I was able to resolve the issue. Just `sudo apt install gettext` was sufficient.